# How to use a local variable value out it function in flutter?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I had received two values as parameters of a function and now I have to use that values out of that function but i am receiving null values for those values.

```
String title;
String type;


void _addNewMedicine(String medTitle, String medType) {

title = medTitle;   // the value of medTitle is assigned to title

type = medType;     // the value of medType is assigned to type

final newMed = Items(productname: medTitle, type: medType);
setState(() {
    _userMedicine.add(newMed);     
    },
);
}
```

If I used `print(medTitle)` or `print(medType)` then the output is `null`.

So please someone help!!!

Thank you in advance...

Comment: are you sure you are accessing those variable after this method called ?

Answer (score 0):

Move your assignment statements into the setState function so the state rebuilds. Without rebuilding the state other widgets and functions will use the old values.

```
setState(
      () {
        title = medTitle;   // the value of medTitle is assigned to title
        type = medType; 
        _userMedicine.add(newMed);
      },
    );
```